# npm shrinkwrap extraneous module

Tags: node.js, npm

There is the following problem - I installed all modules and I'm trying to make npm-shrinkwrap.json file:

```
npm shrinkwrap
```

But I always get the following error:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 14.3.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/4.1.2/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "shrinkwrap"
npm ERR! node v4.1.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1

npm ERR! Problems were encountered
npm ERR! Please correct and try again.
npm ERR! extraneous: core-js@1.2.6 /Users/ulnda/projects/folder/node_modules/my-module/node_modules/webdriverio/node_modules/core-js
npm ERR! extraneous: core-js@1.2.6 /Users/ulnda/projects/folder/node_modules/core-js
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/ulnda/projects/folder/npm-debug.log
```

What does it mean? How can I fix it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try `npm prune` before shrinkwrapping.

Comment: Didn't work for me at first, had to delete the node_modules folder and re-install deps from scratch, then it was fine.